# Issue while reading file from s3 into h2o after upgrading to h2o R package 3.14.0.3

Tags: r, amazon-s3, h2o

Facing issues in reading file from s3 after upgrading from h2o 3.10 to h2o 3.14

I am using the following format to read a file from s3 to h2o[using AWS RStudio standalone instance]

```
h2o.importFile(path = "s3n://<AWS_ACCESS_KEY>:<AWS_SECRET_KEY>@bucket/path/to/file.csv")
```

The above works with the old h2o package [3.10] but throws the below error with h2o r package [3.14]

> "Error in h2o.importFolder(path, pattern = "", destination_frame = destination_frame,  :all files failed to import"

I have gone through the migration documentation below but can't seem to find any changes regarding this.

Link to [documentation](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/product/cloud-integration/ec2-and-s3.rst).

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression which we have encountered very recently, and a JIRA is filed as below:

https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4930

We are actively working on to fix this issue in next H2O release. I will updated here as soon as we have a fix ready and available.